# Qualifier doesn't work (it's really weird)

Tags: spring

The xmlBean works very well(when the definition of stampyDataSource bean is commented, there was error). But the mysqlDataSource didn't. Couldn't figure out why.

class

```
public class MyXmlBean {
public void test(){
    System.out.println("AAAAAAAAA");
}
}
```

spring.xml

```
<bean id="sjnDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rule360_site" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="255" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="2" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="1200" />
</bean>

<bean id="stampyDataSource"  class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hive2://192.168.99.100:10000" />
    <property name="username" value="" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="255" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="2" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="1200" />
</bean>
```

Where use

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sjnDataSource")
private BasicDataSource mysqlDataSource;


@Autowired
@Qualifier("first")
private MyXmlBean xmlBean;
```

Error

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field mysqlDataSource in com.paypal.risk.dna.rca.GreetingController required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - sjnDataSource: defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring.xml]
    - stampyDataSource: defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring.xml]

Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:    Error creating bean with name 'greetingController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mysqlDataSource': Error creating bean with name 'sjnDataSource' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: sjnDataSource,stampyDataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sjnDataSource' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: sjnDataSource,stampyDataSource

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this (facing the same problem).